# Modern monolitical application

Tags: message-queue, bounded-contexts

I know in these days microservice architecture is the best of :) But we create application on demand so customer is who will determine if application will be on cloud or not. We have old application which we need to modernize to decrease complexity and coupling. It is classic application with many logic in stored procedures. I read about DDD and I think bounded context is nice idea how to decrease complexity. But when there are bounded contexts which are separated, how do they communicate together? In microservice architecture there could be RPC or message queuing system. How to do when I want to create communication between bounded contexts in monolith which they are low coupled? Do you have some experiences?

Comment: This is very broad topic and can’t be answered succinctly here. Also micro services are only best when they are, they aren’t a silver bullet. Nor is DDD. They need to be applied properly and only when appropriate. In any case there are lots of ways to communicate and even calling methods in other objects may be separation enough. But there’s not much information you’ve given here about what the application, platform, etc is.

Comment: Thank you. I know DDD is more about philosofie but using bounded context could be nice option for us. Yes, mediator pattern could be used.